# if-else statement output always else in httpurlconnection

Tags: android

I've a code to get return success from server into android like this:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        is, "UTF-8"), 8);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line + "\n");
}
is.close();
String response = sb.toString();
//HERE YOU HAVE THE VALUE FROM THE SERVER
Log.d("Your Data", response);

//if(response == "0"){ still not fix
if(response.equals("0")){
    Log.d("berhasil","keknya");
    db.updateContact(new Contact(idsql,null,1,null));
}
else{
    Log.d("Error", "ubah data");
}
```

in my logcat, the output of `log.d("your data", response)` is 0 but the statement always throw to else like here below:

[image: logcat]

how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You build your `StringBuilder` response line by line using the following logic:

```
sb.append(line + "\n");
```

So if you had only a single response of `0`, then your string builder would actually contain this:

```
0\n
```

If this conjecture be correct, then if you trim whitespace and then compare to zero you should get the result you expect:

```
if (response.trim().equals("0")) {
    Log.d("berhasil", "keknya");
    db.updateContact(new Contact(idsql, null, 1, null));
}
else {
    Log.d("Error", "ubah data");
}
```

Note that if you just want to check the server response code then the `HttpURLConnection` API already exposes a way to do that:

```
try {
    URL url = new URL("http://www.someurl.com");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

    if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        server_response = readStream(conn.getInputStream());
        Log.v("index", server_response);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be some space within a response and so the `if` does not execute,
Try changing the condition to this:

```
if(response.trim().equals("0"))
```

`trim` will remove any initial and final spaces and give you the only the pure `String` without spaces at the end or beginning.